# Difference between « n'en plus pouvoir » and « en avoir marre »

Tags: choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

Is there a difference between the expressions « n'en plus pouvoir » and « en avoir marre »? I think they both generally have the meaning of being fed up with something, but I wasn't sure if there was some other gradation of meaning I'm missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***N'en plus pouvoir*** can be used whatever the context while ***en avoir marre*** is colloquial.

***N'en plus pouvoir*** also includes the meaning of ***en avoir marre*** but can be stronger. The former might mean you are physically exhausted and can no more do something while the latter might just mean you are fed up with it but will continue to put up with it.

Answer (score 2):

*Je n'en peux plus* = I can't stand it any more.
*J'en ai marre.* = I am fed up with it.

Answer (score 1):

***Je n'en peux plus*** has a wider range of meaning. [LawlessFrench](https://www.lawlessfrench.com/expressions/jen-peux-plus/) explains

Synonyms
***Despair***

- je craque

***Fatigue***

- je suis à bout de forces
- je suis crevé
- je suis épuisé

***Irritation***

- je craque
- je m’énerve

The same post adds:

> ***J’en peux plus*** indicates ***despair***, so it’s not quite the same thing as *ras-le-bol* or **j’en ai marre**, which express ***frustration or anger***.